# Modify tabs in managed Lightning Application

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps

After searching a bit, I cannot find any way or information as to how, if possible, to modify the Tabs (order or which one are shown or not) in a managed Lightning Application.

When I go to the apps and I edit the managed Apps, the select items section seems disabled (at least the buttons are).

[image: Disabled Select Items]

I am wondering how I am supposed to modify that or upgrade it (if possible I suppose)? Lightning Applications cannot be deleted when managed and its fine, but most of the settings seems locked and I cannot find any information concerning this.

There's no error message or anything either so I am a bit clueless.

Comment: Also, it seems like I cannot modify the Profile Assignments either from the Edit App dialog; its also read-only. I can modify it though if I go through each Profile individually, so that lead to me think I can probably modify the tabs but from another window (Couldn't find anything yet in Salesforce Classic to modify a Lightning Application).

Comment: Just to make sure, you have full permissions as an admin correct? Also is this a standard app or a custom app?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is, but according to the documentation [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm), lightning apps are upgradable.

Comment: I do have full permissions, and indeed they are upgradable; the problem is that the interface in lightning does not permit any change to the items that are displayed (the tabs) for a given Lightning Application. If the application is classic, you can go in classic to modify it but a lightning application seem  to be only modifiable from the Lightning Experience (which has all controls disabled).

Comment: Also, the app itself can be modified; when you create a new Tab and no the third step add it to the Lightning Application, everything work as expected. The Select Items window is still disabled but the new tab is added in the right column and included in the app but you can only remove it from the app by deleting it. Basically, still seems like there no way to manually edit the app and its the lightning interface that is problematic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed as of Winter17, it is now possible to edit the tab the same way as an unmanaged app would let you do.